# Nexus 3.1 as a docker proxy for DockerHub seems to require authentication but how?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, nexus3

I'm using Docker Toolbox 1.12.3 on Windows 7.  I've configured Nexus OSS 3.1.0-04 to have a Docker Proxy repository to connect to DockerHub.

When I try to run

`docker run 192.168.161.103:10001/hello-world`

I get image not found.  When I look in the Nexus log files I get the following errors:

> 2016-11-23 17:09:59,244+0000 WARN  [qtp253940842-402] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET
>   /v2/hello-world/manifests/latest: 401 -
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception:
>   authentication required 2016-11-23 17:09:59,244+0000 WARN 
>   [qtp253940842-402] admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET
>   /v2/hello-world/manifests/latest: 404 -
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception$ManifestUnknownByTag:
>   manifest unknown 2016-11-23 17:09:59,260+0000 WARN  [qtp253940842-402]
>   admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers -
>   Error: GET /v2/hello-world/manifests/latest: 404 -
>   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception$ManifestUnknownByTag:
>   manifest unknown

Docker is configured with `192.168.161.103` (Nexus) configured as an insecure registry as I'm using a self-signed certificate to connect to Nexus.

How do I configure Nexus 3 to connect to DockerHub using the authentication credentials that it's expecting?

Comment: I believe you should just need to do docker login to the registry, give that a shot!

Comment: Specific error from docker command run would help here.

Comment: @DarthHater provided you the correct answer, you need to login to your local (proxy) repository first

Comment: In the log iit shows the user name - admin, so the request is authenticated. I'm having the same problem. I'm logged in, but can't pull.